# docker exec command not running on docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I am trying to run a zip command from my local machine onto a running docker container but it seems to run the zip command on my host machine and not on the container.

Command: `docker exec CONTAINER zip -r /root/python.zip *`

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER /bin/bash -c "zip -r /root/python.zip *"
```

OR

```
docker exec -it CONTAINER /bin/sh -c "zip -r /root/python.zip *"
```